# How To add more element to nav_link on current_page?

Tags: navigation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, urlhelper, current-page

I have some static pages in a navigation menu. I want to add more element to the item which is currently displaying.

navigation on view layout/adminzor.html.erb

```
<ul class='main-nav'>
    <%= nav_link 'Dashboard', adminzor_path %>
</ul>
```

on application_helper.rb

```
def nav_link(link_text, link_path)
  class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''
    content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
      link_to link_text, link_path
    end
 end
```

and output

```
<ul class='main-nav'>
   <li class="active">
      <a href="/adminzor">Dashboard</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

because I'm using the nav_link helper with Twitter Bootstrap's nav component which prefers links to be wrapped inside li tags and the "active" class applied to the outer li.
and i add some element on view such as

```
<%= nav_link adminzor_path, :class => "light" do %>
  <div class="ico"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i></div>
  Dashboard
<% end %>
```

and helper

```
def nav_link(link_text, link_path)
      class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''
        content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
          link_to link_path do
           link_text
          end
        end
   end
```

but error

```
ArgumentError in Adminzor/dashboards#index

Showing c:/Sites/zionrails/app/views/layouts/adminzor.html.erb where line #44 raised:

wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

i want to output such as

```
<ul class='main-nav'>
<li class="active">
 <a href="/adminzor" class="light">
    <div class="ico">
       <i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>
    </div>Dashboard
 </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Are there any other solutions? thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved**

application_helper.rb

```
def is_active?(link_path)
  if current_page?(link_path)
    "active"
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

and on layout/adminzor.html.erb such as

```
<li class="<%= is_active?(adminzor_path) %>">
                <%= link_to adminzor_path, :class => 'light' do %>
                <div class="ico"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i></div>
                Dashboard
                <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  def menu_link(link_text, icon_type, link_path)
    class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''

    content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
      link_to link_path do
        content_tag(:i, '', :class => icon_type) + link_text
      end
    end

  end
```

And the call:

```
<%= menu_link('My lists', 'icon-list', user_lists_path(@user)) %>
```